# Changing WPF DatePicker Format before saving into DB

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xaml, datepicker

I have a WPF DatePicker which formats is 'dd-MMM-yyyy'.
But now the issue is, i'm using SQLite and my DBTable DateTime Columns default format is 'yyyy-MM-dd'. 
Please i need help on how to convert the DatePicker Selected Value to 'yyyy-MM-dd' using C# before saving it into the Table Column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to format the selected date:

```
 DateTime date = (DateTime)datePicker.SelectedDate;
 string result = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

For more information about custom date/time format in .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx